# Fulfill order after Successful payment Stripe Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments

I have a tiny rails application. Currently, the subscriptions are active with my application with Stripe & [Pay Gem](https://github.com/pay-rails/pay), Which is pretty straightforward. But now I am having an issue or I don't know how I can add some custom action after successful payment.

So here is what I want to do.

I have a model called Theme & the Model has a file field. Now I want after the payment user will get an email with the link of the file.

Anyone here can give me some direction on how can I do it?

Update:

I have got some codes from [pay documentation](https://github.com/pay-rails/pay/blob/master/docs/stripe/1_overview.md) But don't know how to implement them.

```rb
Pay::Webhooks.delegator.subscribe "stripe.checkout.session.completed", FulfillCheckout.new
Pay::Webhooks.delegator.subscribe "stripe.checkout.session.async_payment_succeeded", FulfillCheckout.new

class FulfillCheckout
  def call(event)
    object = event.data.object

    if object.payment_status == "paid"
      # Handle fulfillment
    end
  end
end
```

If anyone can guide me through this?

Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to solve it by adding

```
Pay::Webhooks.delegator.subscribe "stripe.checkout.session.completed", FulfillCheckout.new Pay::Webhooks.delegator.subscribe "stripe.checkout.session.async_payment_succeeded", FulfillCheckout.new
```

to Pay Initializer file

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used the Pay Gem before, but in the docs, there's a description as to what needs to be done after getting a successful payment:

> Fulfilling orders after Checkout completed
>
> For one-time payments, you'll need to add a webhook listener for the
> Checkout stripe.checkout.session.completed and
> stripe.checkout.session.async_payment_succeeded events. Some payment
> methods are delayed so you need to verify the payment_status ==
> "paid". The async payment succeeded event fires when delayed payments
> are complete.

So based on that, in your webhook listener, you would trigger an SMTP or some other way of emailing and have a link to the `theme.file_name`. This is handled differently based on how you are delivering emails to your users.

Comment: Hi @RailsDevNewbie
Thanks for Pointing out. I have seen the docs But I am not sure of the code they added.


so this part
 
`Pay::Webhooks.delegator.subscribe "stripe.checkout.session.completed", FulfillCheckout.new`
`Pay::Webhooks.delegator.subscribe "stripe.checkout.session.async_payment_succeeded", FulfillCheckout.new`
```

I have to run from Console?

& Create a model c& Add the conditions on the model? 

How can I do it from controller ANy Hints?

Comment: Managed to solve it thanks @RailsDevNewbie for trying to help